# Documentation for Visual Studio Fonts and Colors elements

Tags: visual-studio, ide, customization

I am trying to change the colors of the text editor in Visual Studio 22 Community Edition.

I am doing so via the following menu

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor
[image]

I am having a hard time understanding which element is named what, and which name references what (Plain Text, Selected Text, etc).

If anyone could share documentation as to what each element means it would be great. Specifically what do we call the highlighted line number for the current line the cursor is on (line 11 in black).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the highlighted line number for the current line is:
**"Line Number (Current)"**